# What is the meaning of Shuchi in Sanskrit, in the context of Hinduism?

Tags: vedas

We use 2 words when it comes to cleanliness in Hinduism. They are "Shuchi" and "Shubratha". "Shubratha" can be described as neatness / cleanliness if you consider its usage in other Indian languages. Then what does "Shuchi" mean? I don't think it also means cleanliness.

I can give you a reference for the usage of "Shuchi" in phalashruthi of [Sri Sukham](http://www.drikpanchang.com/lyrics/stotram/maha-lakshmi/shree-suktam-with-lakshmi-suktam.html?lang=en) as below:

> Yah ***Shucih*** Prayato Bhuutvaa Juhu-Yaad-Aajyam-Anvaham ।
>   Suuktam Pancadasharcam Ca Shriikaamah Satatam Japet ॥16॥

Comment: You can use [blockquotes](http://meta.stackexchange.com/editing-help#simple-blockquotes) when you quote a shlokha or stotram.

Comment: Shubhrata Does not mean neatness it is a term referring to whiteness of clothes or to represent the flawlessness , like the flawless white saree of Goddess Saraswati in her shloka she is described as yaa kundendu tushar haar dhawala yaa `Shubhra` vastra vrita.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I've checked from the Sanskrit to English directory that I have and found that Suchi means clean.

> [image: screen-shot]

---

You can also check at Sanskritdirectory [शुचि](http://sanskritdictionary.com/%C5%9Buci/236022/1) and [शुचिः](http://sanskritdictionary.com/%C5%9Buci%E1%B8%A5/311414/3)

> [image: screenshot]

And

> [image: screenshot]

---

Oh! Actually the site you've referenced in question has also meanings and English translation. Check [this](http://www.drikpanchang.com/lyrics/stotram/maha-lakshmi/translation/shree-suktam-with-lakshmi-suktam.html?shlok=16)

Read meaning:

> Those who after Becoming Bodily **Clean** and Devotionally Disposed perform Sacrificial Offering with Butter Day after Day,
>   By Constantly Reciting the Fifteen Verses of Sri Suktam will have their Longing for Sri Fulfilled by the Grace of Devi Lakshmi.

---

By the way, here the word used is `शुचिः` and you can also refer **vedabase** for Shrimad Bhagvat Mahapuran verse [SB 11.3.49](http://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/11/3/49) and [CC Madhya 23.109](http://www.vedabase.com/en/cc/madhya/23/109) verse.

Comment: As you may know. We don't have straight meaning in english for all Sanskrit words. It's because the same words gives different means at different places. The languages used in usual Sanskrit language and Vedas may be different sometimes. That's the reason why we have "Nighantu" for normal Sanskrit and "Niriktham" for Vedas. Which may be called simply as dictionaries in english but they are different. To translate Vedas, Upanishads, and stotrams our simple proficiency isn't enough. We need to have something called "sampradaya" or tradition which can only be learnt from gurus. So shuchi isnt sim

Comment: So shuchi isnt simple cleanliness or purity.

Comment: @SrikanthMyakam for more meaning of शुचि, refer [sanskritdirectory](http://sanskritdictionary.com/?iencoding=iast&q=%E0%A4%B6%E0%A5%81%E0%A4%9A%E0%A4%BF&lang=sans&action=Search)

Comment: @SrikanthMyakam I've recently revised answer adding reference to vedabase, check

Comment: Need resources Pandya.